# Finding maximum independent set in sparse graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a directed graph such that each node has out-degree exactly $1$. What is an algorithm to find a [maximum independent set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory))? Is it possible to do this in $O(|V|)$ time? (Note that $|V|=|E|$ in the given setting.)

Comment: This can be solved by noticing that the graph is basically cycles with tentacles. Then, you can use dynamic programming on each of these octopus.